# Key for unique index gets truncated

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

We replicate data from Google Datastore to Google Cloud SQL.
The string representation of the key is used as the primary key for the MySQL table.
Entities with parents tend to have quite long keys (120 characters is not unusual).

Lately, we are observing problems, an IntegrityError is thrown:

```
IntegrityError: (1062, u"Duplicate entry 'xxx' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

Where xxx are the first 64 characters of the key that is 100 to 115 characters long

It seems that only the first 64 characters of the varchar(255) column are inspected. Is there any way to change it? At the moment it's not an option to use shorter keys.

Here's the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `_key` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_key`)
)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that's doing the replication?

Comment: Is the string only 64 characters?

Comment: No, up to 115 characters, Google Appengine encodes the entity name and key name or id, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key